# Clicks on window stop working after SetParent(NULL)

Tags: c++, winapi

Given two windows, a parent and child, if I call `SetParent()` on the `child` passing `NULL` as the last parameter, the `child` window doesn't respond to clicks anymore.

I noticed that the `child` window responds when I use `PostMessage()` to send `WM_LBUTTONDOWN/UP` to it.

What am I missing?

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"");
HWND child = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_CHILD);
SetParent(child, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [`SetParent` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent):

> For compatibility reasons, `SetParent` does not modify the `WS_CHILD` or `WS_POPUP` window styles of the window whose parent is being changed. Therefore, **if `hWndNewParent` is NULL, you should also clear the `WS_CHILD` bit and set the `WS_POPUP` style after calling `SetParent`**. Conversely, if `hWndNewParent` is not NULL and the window was previously a child of the desktop, you should clear the `WS_POPUP` style and set the `WS_CHILD` style before calling `SetParent`.
>
> When you change the parent of a window, you should synchronize the UISTATE of both windows. For more information, see `WM_CHANGEUISTATE` and `WM_UPDATEUISTATE`.

Try this:

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"");
HWND child = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_CHILD);
SetParent(child, NULL);
LONG_PTR style = GetWindowLongPtr(child, GWL_STYLE);
SetWindowLongPtr(child, GWL_STYLE, (style & ~WS_CHILD) | WS_POPUP);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer, i tried your code but the window still didn't respond to clicks,  the window I'm testing is the `BlueStacks 5`. **How to reproduce:** open `BlueStacks` start *any* app, run the code, the window is 'detached' from the parent but it didn't respond to clicks anymore. Using a tool like `spy++` I was able to see that the window is receiving all mouse messages correctly.

Comment: I'm doing this to be able to launch any app without the BlueStacks caption/sidebar buttons, it would look like a borderless mode.

Comment: @Katia you can't just manipulate someone else's app any which way you want. Clearly the app in question wasn't designed to be split up the way you are doing and still behave properly.

Comment: It should be possible by applying/removing the correct window styles, dont? why does it work when I send `PostMessage` with `WM_LBUTTON`? and not when i click on it

Comment: "It should be possible by applying/removing the correct window styles". This is your mistake. This belief and expectation of yours is incorrect. You can't expect to manipulate another window from another process like this.